# How to access internet from HYPER-V guest machine which uses IPv6 Only?

Tags: ipv6, hyper-v, windows-server-2012, 6to4

I have `Windows Server 2012` installed in my laptop with `Hyper-V` activated.

I have a wireless network interface with which I can connect to the Internet from the physical machine as well has the virtual machines(using external virtual switches) with `IPv4` addressing.

What I would like to know is **how to connect IPv6 only VMs to the internet throught the wireless interface given that the wireless interface must be addressed in IPv4?**

Should I use NAT64 and DNS64 and if so how?

Comment: Can you not install/enable IPv4 on the VMs for some reason? Are you determined to route traffic through the host? Why not bind the NIC instead, and let the infrastructure router provide the IPv6 routing for the VMs?

Comment: Actually the infrastructure router is pure IPv4 which means I need to route traffic throught the host.